# elementary OS Freya freezes when booting

Tags: boot

When I boot elementary OS Freya, it freezes with the pulsating logo. Pressing "Esc", I see that the last line is `* Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon     [ OK ]`.

I have found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323598/stuck-starting-cups-browsed) of the ubuntu forums, which describes the same problem (except that they run 13.04). However, when I try to mount the elementary partition with `sudo mount /dev/mapper/nvidia_abcdefg1 /mnt` it says that the folder `nvidia_abcdefg1` does not exist.

I tried to mount the partition with the Files applications and then opening the folder with the terminal. After executing the commands and rebooting the computer, the problem persists.

The computer is Acer TravelMate P253-E and it has another Windows 7 partition.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into a live environment

Create a simple text file in `/etc/init`  named `cups-browsed.override`. In this file just write one word i.e. `manual`.

Follow these steps to do the above:

`gksudo gedit /etc/init/cups-browsed.override`

Write `manual` in the first line and save.

On booting you wont have the problem caused by this remote printing service.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it when I get back the laptop (I'm helping a friend that is new to Linux). Will it work with `sudo nano` instead of `gksudo gedit`?

Comment: Sure, It'll work good. All you need is a editor being run in a root mode.